# Load thumbnail photos of Active Directory users as a domain user (not controller) to Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, active-directory

Is it possible, as a user in a domain (without administrative rights), to add thumbnail photos of my co-workers so they'll appear in the thumbnail photo cube in Outlook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to be delegated the permission to do it by an administrator of the Active Directory domain.

Here's a tutorial (there are several out there on the Internet) on how to perform the delegation:

- [How do I delegate control of the thumbnail photo field?](https://support.exclaimer.com/hc/en-gb)

I'd spell out how to do it directly here in my answer, but you only asked if it was possible. :)

Here's a couple links with some good info on Delegation in AD in general:

- [Delegating administration (MS TechNet)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc778807%28v=ws.10%29)
- [Implementing Active Directory Delegation of Administration](https://web.archive.org/web/20161130233933/http://www.windowsecurity.com:80/articles-tutorials/authentication_and_encryption/Implementing-Active-Directory-Delegation-Administration.html)

Here's a link regarding doing the photos specifically:

- [How to manage employee photographs with Active Directory](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/how-to-manage-employee-photographs-with-active-directory/)

And a tool the purports to help (never used it personally):

- [Update your Active Directory picture with the AD Photo Edit Tool (MSDN Blogs)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160206085012/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/croman/archive/2011/04/07/update-your-active-directory-picture-with-the-ad-photo-edit-tool.aspx)